# いつもフォルダが認識されない

Tags: python

dataディレクトリ直下に、imagesフォルダとtest.pyがあります。imagesフォルダ内にはdata1・data2の２つのフォルダがあり、data1・data2には1.png・2.png・・・と画像が入っています。今このdata1・data2の中にある画像を取り出したいです。
test.pyに

```
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--img_dir")
    data_dir = parser.parse_args()
    if data_dir.img_dir is None or not os.path.exists(data_dir.img_dir):
       raise Exception("data_dir does not exist")
    input_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(data_dir.img_dir, "*.jpg"))
```

とコードを書きました。このコードを

```
python test.py images
```

と実行すると、いつも"data_dir does not exist"とエラーが出ます。なぜファイルを指定しているのにこのようにいつも出るのかわかりません。調べながらこのコードを書き、そんなことはないと思うのですが、os.path.exists(data_dir.img_dir)ではフルパスじゃないと認識しないのでしょうか？どのように直せばよいでしょうか？

Comment: `python test.py --img_dir images/data1` などとするのではないでしょうか。。。それと、`import os` と `import glob` を追加する必要がある様に思われます。

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄で @metropolis さんも書かれていますが、`data`をカレントディレクトリとすると、スクリプトと画像ファイルの位置関係は以下の様になっているはずなので、`test.py`から画像を参照するためには`images/data1/`,`images/data2/`, ... が相対パスになるはずです。

```
test.py
images/data1/1.png
images/data1/2.png
images/data2/1.png
images/data2/2.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythonでは実行するスクリプトがあるフォルダがカレントフォルダとなります。フォルダ構成を見るとtest.py, data1, data2は同じimagesフォルダにあるので、今のコードと構成では`python test.py data1`などとする必要がある気がします。